What is the meaning of "I am digging this groove"
In the movie "Irish Wish",
there is a line
"I am digging this groove"
Good morning, everyone.
[all] Good morning.
[Heather] I’m digging this groove.
Uh, darling?
Oh.
Allow me.
Thank you.

What is the meaning of digging this groove?
I know dig means 'like', and the noun groove is defined as "an enjoyable or exciting experience" in the merriam-webster dictionary https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/groove.
So does this mean something like 'I am enjoying  the current situation/experience'?
The script is in https://scrapsfromtheloft.com/movies/irish-wish-transcript/
And I screen-captured a little bit for the context here. https://youtu.be/GTPCMHLhoNw
Thank you.

It's much better to explain the context in your question rather than via links. External links often break; YouTube videos are often taken down quite quickly, especially if they're breaches of copyright.

I haven't seen the movie but the comment seems to be saying "I like this (new) Maddie".  You could say "I'm digging this groove" about a song you're hearing for the first time, a song you like.

I think it's just an incompetent scriptwriter completely mangling 1960s "hippy-speak". Which wouldn't be appropriate to the context even if the actual utterance was idiomatically accurate (hippies didn't use terms like Darling and Allow me as cited).

...the first review I looked at on IMDB includes Weaknesses were in the cliche unrealistic dialogue (especially with side characters) and... I haven't seen the movie either, but most Hollywood movies make a real dog's dinner of Irish accents anyway, even if the scriptwriters set out the right words.

You can still hear this phrase used unironically in smalltown America,  though the tone of voice of the person in the movie is rather urbane-hipsterish.

It's not clear even from the video clip whether the music is simply soundtrack or is supposed to be audible to the characters, but most hippie-slang usages evolved from a musical one, in which a music's "groove" is its engaging qualities. She could be speaking whimsically about the rather tame music in the scene, or speaking more broadly of "this situation, this room, its inhabitants, their clothes, the overall gestalt."

Thank you all for all the comments. Regarding the copy right, the YouTube says "
Copyright-protected content found. The owner allows the content to be used on YouTube." on this video clip.  Thank Stuart F for pointing this out. I think the music is soundtrack inaudible to the characters.  Thank you.

This is 1960s slang.  While your understanding of the "meaning" is correct, you are missing the context.  This is language is something that a hippy would say while sitting in a field and taking drugs.  It's not something that a smart woman in a posh house would normally say.
So either it is being said ironically, as a joke, or she misunderstands the social scene she is in.  That is we either laugh with her, or at her, for using the "wrong kind of language".

Sometimes adults talking to the younger generation will try to use their slang to seem "hip". But they often misuse it, so it doesn't sound natural and has the opposite effect of emphasizing how unhip they are.

I am the OP.  Thank you James K. for answering my question.  It is really hard for a non-native speaker to be able to catch those meanings or context without the background knowledge.
